# 'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet' to export to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I need to EXPORT an access table from ACCESS to EXCEL. There are 618499 rows. I tried simple method: right-click - export - excel. It worked only when I choose export with format (without format created blank excel document), but it is not convenient because I'll have to create 10 documents. I tried to use this code but it became red and did not work:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(
    [acExport],
    [acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml],
    [tab_1],
    ["C:\Users\admin\Desktop\import_2014\final.xlsx"],
    [True])
```

1. What should I change in it?
2. How should I type it in a module.
3. Or maybe you can offer another simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All VBA code must be in a sub or function, that is in a module.

Get rid of all those `[]`, and if you want to put each parameter into a new line, use the line concatenation symbol `_`

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
    acExport, _
    acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
    "tab_1", _
    "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\import_2014\final.xlsx", _
    True
```

**EDIT**

Either use `Call`:

```
Call DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
    "tab_1", "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\import_2014\final.xlsx", True)
```

or omit the parentheses:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
    "tab_1", "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\import_2014\final.xlsx", True
```

Comment: @OlegVovk: see edit, VBA is peculiar about parentheses.

Comment: @Andre451, apparently it worked but a Message box shown an error '3035' saying "system resource exceeded". I tried both variants. I have 8 GB operative memory is it not enough?

Comment: @OlegVovk: Another alternative is: `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "tab_1", acFormatXLSX, "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\import_2014\final.xlsx"` but I don't know if it will work better for 600k rows.

Comment: @Andre451, It works but a message box says that The clipboard cannot handle such big number of rows and advised to divide my table into several tables. It is very strange. It means that none of methods works and the only method I can use is to divide my table into smaller tables. I don't understand the reason why the simplest method doesn't work (right-click-export-excel) and why there is not enough space for your method.

Comment: @OlegVovk: You can create saved queries e.g. `SELECT * FROM tab_1 WHERE myPrimaryKey >= 0 AND myPrimaryKey <= 200000` and so on, and then export these queries. It's a hack, but better than dividing your table.

Comment: @Andre451 Thank you for your help. Your hack solution is very I will use it. But I did not have a primary key and the data base is very large, It is 1300000 rows. Instead of exporting from ACCESS to excel, I created an EXCEl file and imported from ACCESS. There were two steps, first, it offered me to import as much as possible, second, I imported the rest. =)